How properly solve failed migration command in docker shell?
I need some help with setting up the database in Docker. All my containers are running successfully, but when I try to run the migration, I get error mention below. Here is my configuration.
docker-compose.yml
services:
  laravel:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: laravelapp
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./deploy/Dockerfile
    # allocate as many volumes as necessary, if needed.
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html
      - ../storage/app:/var/www/html/storage/app
    environment:
      APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
      APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      APP_DEBUG: ${APP_DEBUG}
      APP_KEY: ${APP_KEY}
      APP_VERSION: ${APP_VERSION}
      APP_URL: ${APP_URL}
      DB_CONNECTION: mysql
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MAIL_MAILER: ${MAIL_MAILER}
      MAIL_HOST: ${MAIL_HOST}
      MAIL_PORT: ${MAIL_PORT}
      MAIL_USERNAME: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
      MAIL_PASSWORD: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}
      MAIL_ENCRYPTION: ${MAIL_ENCRYPTION}
      MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: ${MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS}
      MAIL_FROM_NAME: ${MAIL_FROM_NAME}
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - n-laravel
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - v-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - n-laravel
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

this is my .env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=shitdate
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

and I'm getting this error
/var/www/html # php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for database failed: Name does not resolve (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length)  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for database failed: Name does not resolve (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'shitdate' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', ' as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'shitdate' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:825
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:825
    821▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    822▕                 );
    821▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    822▕                 );
    823▕             }
    823▕             }
    824▕
  ➜ 825▕             throw new QueryException(
    824▕
  ➜ 825▕             throw new QueryException(
    826▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    827▕             );
    828▕         }
    829▕     }
    826▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    827▕             );
    828▕         }
    829▕     }
    827▕             );
    828▕         }
    829▕     }
    829▕     }

      +41 vendor frames 

  42  artisan:13
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::handleCommand(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))

admin user in database has all permissions necessary for accesing database granted. I can't really figure out whats wrong with setup of databse. I'm using MySQL MariaDB.


there is no such thing as mysql mariadb. There is mysql and there is mariadb. These are two increasingly incompatible database products 2) if you read the error message, then you xan see that this issue has nothing to do  with php or laravel or mysql. Your code cannot resolve the host name mysql, so probably mysql container is not running or the network is misconfigured.


What is the exact command you're trying to run?  Where are you trying to run it?
